Decoding ByteA data in postgresql
Using decode function for decoding a ByteA data.
This runs successfully but some non-english character such as 'ä' comes as '\334'
Anything need to be changed on the below code
Select replace(replace(encode(cont_json,'escape'),E'\\000',''),'\\','\')
From dbo.cont_encode where cont_ID=2

Tried to use convert_from(decode('column', 'base64'), 'utf-8') and other decompress techniques but no luck

It's always a good idea to provide a way to reproduce the problem. You can include ddl and insert statements and/or create a https://dbfiddle.uk/S9ZOHCkV

You say you want to decode something (JSON text?), but you haven't stated how it is encoded! bytea means nothing, it might be image data or something else, not text. How is the data generated? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant info, as well as some example values and the expected results for them.

Data has been migrated from SQL server to postgresql. SQL server was using decompress() to decode the json and I am getting  'ä' but in postgresql using the decode function, shown in question , I am getting '\334' instead of 'ä'

It all depends on the encoding you used  for these data. If you say, "huh, encoding, what?", let's assume you are on Windows and used their single-byte encoding. Then the answer would be
SELECT convert_from(cont_json, 'win1252')
FROM ... WHERE ...


Getting invalid sequence for encoding ''UTF8" SQL state 22021

Then I guess you will have to figure out what encoding is actually used and use that instead of win1252.

It was migrated from sql server and decompress() was used.

You could select the bytea value and add it to the question. Then we can perhaps find out what the encoding is.
